# Difference between ViewSet and GenericViewSet?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have been a little confused lately with GenericViewSets and ViewSets. It started off by thinking what is the difference between APIView and GenericAPIView.

A little search and I found out that APIView uses HTTP verbs(get, put post, etc) as their method names and they have to be explicitly implemented, whereas in GenericAPIView the method names are actions (list, create, destroy, update, etc) which are automatically mapped to the correct method call. But even these HAVE to be implemented.

However, we can add mixins on top of GenericAPIView or use generics and then we do not have to implement the methods if they follow a basic CRUD pattern. Declaring just the queryset (get_queryset) and serializer_class(get_serializer) will suffice.

My question is if the difference between ViewSets and GenericViewSets is same as APIView and GenericAPIView? Also, what if I want my class to inherit only the GenericViewSets( or GenericAPIView, for that matter), without using any mixins?

How would GenericViewSets be any different from ViewSets then?

PS. This is the image that got me thinking about everything.
[image: Confusion Generator]

Comment: A `GenericViewSet` or `GenericAPIView` offers utility methods like `get_object`, etc. that check object permissions. Therefore if you work with some model, you almost always use a `GenericViewSet`/`GenericAPIView` over a `ViewSet`/`APIView`.

Answer (score 0):

#### (GenericAPIView) and (APIView) Both are class based view for developing API with Django Rest Framework

#### but it have diffent diffent approch for Developing API

#### --------GenericAPIView (CRUD)--------

```
# List and Create - PK Not Required (Can Create and view Data)
class LCStudentAPI(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin, CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

# Retrieve Update and Destroy - PK Required (Can Retrieve,Update and Delete Data)
class RUDStudentAPI(GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

#### ---------------- APIView (CRUD) ---------------

```py
class StudentAPI(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        id = pk
        if id is not None:
            stu = Student.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = StudentSerializer(stu)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        stu = Student.objects.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(stu, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg':'Data Created'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    # Complete Data Updated (all fields need)
    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        id = pk
        stu = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(stu, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg':'Complete Data Updated'})
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # Partial Data Updated (Not all fields need)
    def patch(self, request, pk, format=None):
        id = pk
        stu = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(stu, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'msg':'Partial Data Updated'})
        return Response(serializer.errors)



    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        id = pk
        stu = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
        stu.delete()
        return Response({'msg':'Data Deleted'})
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the diff. between APIView and GenericAPIView with a code. However, my original ask was to understand the difference between (GenericViewset and Viewset), without the mixins, and if the difference between the 2 is the same as the difference between APIView and GenericAPIView (as you have explained above).